# Android app crashes on launch build on Xamarin forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-emulator

Not able to launch application build on xamarin forms in android emulator 8.1.

```
public class MainActivity : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }
}
```

My WeatherForYou.Android.csproj file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{22C428F8-4245-43E3-82D2-63B7D3A61DEE}</ProjectGuid>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{EFBA0AD7-5A72-4C68-AF49-83D382785DCF};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <TemplateGuid>{c9e5eea5-ca05-42a1-839b-61506e0a37df}</TemplateGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>WeatherForYou.Droid</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>WeatherForYou.Android</AssemblyName>
    <Deterministic>True</Deterministic>
    <AndroidApplication>True</AndroidApplication>
    <AndroidResgenFile>Resources\Resource.designer.cs</AndroidResgenFile>
    <AndroidResgenClass>Resource</AndroidResgenClass>
    <AndroidManifest>Properties\AndroidManifest.xml</AndroidManifest>
    <MonoAndroidResourcePrefix>Resources</MonoAndroidResourcePrefix>
    <MonoAndroidAssetsPrefix>Assets</MonoAndroidAssetsPrefix>
    <AndroidUseLatestPlatformSdk>false</AndroidUseLatestPlatformSdk>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v8.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <AndroidEnableSGenConcurrent>true</AndroidEnableSGenConcurrent>
    <AndroidUseAapt2>true</AndroidUseAapt2>
    <AndroidHttpClientHandlerType>Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler</AndroidHttpClientHandlerType>
    <NuGetPackageImportStamp>
    </NuGetPackageImportStamp>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>portable</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <AndroidLinkMode>None</AndroidLinkMode>
    <EnableProguard>true</EnableProguard>
    <AndroidSupportedAbis>armeabi-v7a;x86;x86_64</AndroidSupportedAbis>
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
    <AotAssemblies>false</AotAssemblies>
    <EnableLLVM>false</EnableLLVM>
    <AndroidEnableProfiledAot>false</AndroidEnableProfiledAot>
    <BundleAssemblies>false</BundleAssemblies>
    <MandroidI18n />
    <EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>true</EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>
    <AndroidUseAapt2>false</AndroidUseAapt2>
    <AndroidEnableSGenConcurrent>false</AndroidEnableSGenConcurrent>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>portable</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release</OutputPath>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <AndroidManagedSymbols>true</AndroidManagedSymbols>
    <AndroidUseSharedRuntime>false</AndroidUseSharedRuntime>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Mono.Android" />
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
    <Reference Include="System.Numerics" />
    <Reference Include="System.Numerics.Vectors" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms" Version="4.4.0.991265" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Essentials" Version="1.3.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="MainActivity.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Resources\Resource.designer.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="Resources\AboutResources.txt" />
    <None Include="Assets\AboutAssets.txt" />
    <None Include="Properties\AndroidManifest.xml" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable\weather_icon3.webp" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\layout\Tabbar.xml" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\layout\Toolbar.xml" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\values\styles.xml" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\values\colors.xml" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\mipmap-anydpi-v26\icon.xml" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\mipmap-anydpi-v26\icon_round.xml" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\mipmap-hdpi\icon.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\mipmap-hdpi\launcher_foreground.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\mipmap-mdpi\icon.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\mipmap-mdpi\launcher_foreground.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\mipmap-xhdpi\icon.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\mipmap-xhdpi\launcher_foreground.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\mipmap-xxhdpi\icon.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\mipmap-xxhdpi\launcher_foreground.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\mipmap-xxxhdpi\icon.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\mipmap-xxxhdpi\launcher_foreground.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable\weatherphotos.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\WeatherForYou\WeatherForYou.csproj">
      <Project>{6A3BE6BA-AC30-482B-AB39-535FAB67E786}</Project>
      <Name>WeatherForYou</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable\splash_page.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable\splash_screen.xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>
```

Sometimes it launches and splash page comes and then shows below exception on line `base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);`

```
Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException
  Message=Didn't find class "crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.PowerSaveModeBroadcastReceiver" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.goodname.weatherforyou-wOqVUPomH7lrMgQLLS_VMg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.goodname.weatherforyou-wOqVUPomH7lrMgQLLS_VMg==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.goodname.weatherforyou-wOqVUPomH7lrMgQLLS_VMg==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
```

Tried deleting bin & obj folders and clean build for 100 times.

Comment: Strongly advise you to update Visual studio to latest, this is a known issue, updating the IDE should solve this.

Comment: @Umar3x Updated by VS 2019 to the latest version. Still facing the issue...

Comment: ```Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState); ``` is ```Xamarin.Essentials.Platform```

Comment: Does this happens in a new/fresh project? Are you using the latest Visual-Studio 2019?